# Book series about Moon base

Tags: story-identification, novel, moon

Book series following life of a man from pilot, to first man to have sex in space, then later as an astronaut he kills a female astronaut, later he becomes leader of Moon base who has conflict with Earth.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  How many books in the series did you read?  Do you remember any of the cover art?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I suspect this is Ben Bova's [Kinsman](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/ben-bova/the-kinsman-saga/) series

> This amalgamation, then, is the life story of one Chet Kinsman, a
> heroic young military astronaut, and, among other things, **the first
> man to make love in weightless conditions**. He fights in orbit and
> **kills a Russian cosmonaut**, rescues an injured fellow-astronaut on the
> moon, and battles the Washington bureaucracy over establishing a base
> there.

Comment: Thank you.  It was indeed Kinsman.  I had thought it was by Ben Bova but had little luck narrowing it down from all the books he has published.

Comment: If you like my answer, you can click the checkmark to the left of it (underneath the votes).  Glad to help you find your books.